# How to run a local script in mongo shell - Solution load()

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I think this is a very basic question but I'm stuck. I'm connected to remote mongo instance (mLab) via a MongoDB shell. This has been fine for one-liners, but now I want to run larger commands but often, thus the need to do it from an already connected shell.

How can I run my local script.js from the mongo shell and get the output in the shell, as if I'm just running the one-liner per usual?

I was hoping load("script.js") would do it, but it just returns 'true' regardless of the content.

Comment: Basically `mongo <uri> < scriptname.js`. The rest is discussed ( at length ) in the duplicate.

Comment: Yes, I understand how to run from the system shell. The point of difference that I'm seeking to run from the mongo shell which is logged into a remote instance.

Comment: The solution cited works fine for the problem posed in the dupe, but doesn't solve my problem. Appreciate your efforts @NeilLunn

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Execute a JavaScript file

You can specify a .js file to the mongo shell, and mongo will execute the JavaScript directly. Consider the following example:

```
mongo localhost:27017/test myjsfile.js
```

Replace the Localhost URL with your Mlab URL

Or if you are in the shell You can execute a .js file from within the mongo shell, using the load() function, as in the following:

```
load("myjstest.js")
```

refer to this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/)

Modify your script file to print all items in a result cursor , use the following idiom:

```
cursor = db.collection.find();
 while ( cursor.hasNext() ) {
   printjson( cursor.next() );
}
```

Comment: I'm already in the shell.

Comment: Are you not able to run it with the command I gave you

Comment: Sure, I can run that, but I'm seeking to run the local script in an already running shell.

Comment: Yes, load("myjstest.js") looked like It would do the job. I get 'true' in response but I'm not sure if the output is piping elsewhere. Did you get it to work @Karthik? I'd love to know if you got a result.

Comment: Is your Mongo query a find or an insert ? @SteveTaylor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148088/discussion-between-karthik006-and-steve-taylor).